# Class Constructor is not getting called when creating a vector with class objects

Tags: c++

I am creating a vector with class objects as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    public:

        myclass(int a = 0) : x(a)
        {
            cout << "myclass constructor" << endl;
        }

        int x;
};

int main()
{
    vector<myclass> v(2, 1);

    cout << "size : " << v.size() << endl;
    cout << v[0].x << endl;
    cout << v[1].x << endl;
}
```

As per my understanding 2 objects will be created with value '1'. But constructor is getting called only once. When I print the values of the objects, both objects are printing x values as '1'. Below is the output.

```
myclass constructor
size : 2
1
1
```

I couldn't understand why constructor is not getting called twice.

1) Is copy constructor getting called here?

I tried to write copy constructor in the class as below

```
myclass(myclass &obj)
{
    x = obj.x;
    cout << "Copy Constructor" << endl;
}
```

but it is throwing following errors while compiling.

vector.cpp:15:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const myclass’ to ‘myclass&’
vector.cpp:10:9: note: myclass::myclass(int)
         myclass(int a = 0) : x(a)
         ^
vector.cpp:10:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const myclass’ to ‘int’

2) Is there any rule that we should not define copy constructor if we are going to create vector of objects of that class? What are the rules we should follow if we are creating vector with user defined class objects?

Comment: The proper copy constructor would be `myclass(const myclass &obj)`. The `const` part is quite important.

Comment: Your copy constructor is not good. The copy CTOR needs to take a **constant** reference of a myclass object. Not a reference.

Comment: @rodrigo: Yes. I agree. But that shouldn't impact this problem.

Comment: @kadina Well, the answer below disagree with what you just said

Comment: Items are added to vectors by copying them.

Comment: Thanks rodrigo, FrankS101 and HatsuPointerKun.

Comment: @kadina any class where simply copying members by value will fail will need a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
myclass(const myclass &obj)
    {
        x = obj.x;
        cout << "Copy Constructor" << endl;
    }
```

As for part 2, general rule apply : create copy constructor where default member-by member copying will fail.

Answer (score 4):

The copy constructor requires a `const` reference. Use `myclass(const myclass &obj)` for the copy constructor.

---

> As per my understanding 2 objects will be created with value '1'. But
>   constructor is getting called only once.

The constructor is called once and then the object is copied a number of times.

---

Then the picture is clear from the output:

```
myclass constructor
Copy Constructor
Copy Constructor
size : 2
1
1
```

Remember that the vector will also resize and have to copy the elements sometimes.

Comment: Does this mean one object will be created and remaining objects will be copy constructed?

Comment: It definitely looks so

Comment: And are there any rules we should follow if we are creating vector with user defined class objects?

Comment: @kadina: Sure there is! [The rule of three or the rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: @Rodrigo: I mean any functions we need to implement in the class (like overloading <, ==) if we are going to implement a vector with objects of the class because complete reference mentioned that we need to define < and == operators if we are creating vector with the objects of the class.

Comment: @kadina You only need to implement `operator==()` if you intend to compare vectors with `==`. If you try an operation with vectors and fail to implement the proper operation on your class you will get a compiler error.

Comment: @kadina The funny thing with the copy constructor is that if you do not implement it the compiler will generate one for you (if the class has certain properties).